Include acronym with citation with R Markdown/Quarto (using pandoc)
Often when writing, I need to define an acronym with a citation. For example:

One popular statistic is the Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC; Schwarz, 1978).


Unfortunately, I cannot get this to render correctly with citeproc. Here are a few iterations I have tried:
One popular statistic is the Bayesian Information Criterion [BIC; @schwarz-1978].


One popular statistic is the Bayesian Information Criterion [BIC; Schwarz (1978)].


One popular statistic is the Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC; Schwarz [-@bic])


One popular statistic is the Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC; Schwarz (1978)).


One popular statistic is the Bayesian Information Criterion [BIC, @bic]


One popular statistic is the Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC, Schwarz, 1978).


The last example is the closest, but I have to use a comma after the acronym instead of a semi-colon. I believe this is because the semi-colon is normally used to separate citation keys, and in this case the first item is an acronym, not a citation key. Is it possible to include an acronym with a citation in this way?

You could try escaping the semi-colon.
bib.bib Contents
@article{bic,
  title={Estimating the dimension of a model},
  author={Schwarz, G.},
  journal={The Annals of Statistics},
  volume={6},
  pages={461-464},
  year={1978}
}

Quarto Contents
---
title: "Citation Acronym Example"
format: html
editor: visual
bibliography: bib.bib
---

# Desired Output

One popular statistic is the Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC; Schwarz, 1978).

# Escaping Backslash

One popular statistic is the Bayesian Information Criterion [BIC\; @bic]

Result

Reprex files hosted with  on GitHub
